# How to identify why my transaction goes to pool, and how to process them?

Tags: transactions, poa, txpool

I'm working with POA blockchain with three nodes. When I send transaction using geth console, sometimes my transaction goes to txpool and never clear from there.

Is there any way using that we can see the reason why the transaction is stuck in txpool?

How I send a transaction

```
eth.sendTransaction({from:eth.coinbase, to:"0x0ddb39f11611057fec9670a9ba73315e0a634c28", value: web3.toWei(1, "ether")})
```

txpool Inspect

```
> txpool.inspect
{
  pending: {
    0x79b69CD3c0b551c6082482B7Ec9CBB1D0aC5834f: {
      254: "0x0dDb39f11611057fEc9670A9ba73315E0A634c28: 1000000000000000000 wei + 90000 gas × 100000000000 wei"
    }
  },
  queued: {}
}
```

I thought it might be because of my other nodes are not running, hence I have run others nodes and did `miner.start()`, however this transaction doesn't get clear.

Comment: Are new blocks correctly created ? I mean does the value returned by `eth.blockNumber` increases when your sealers are active ?

Comment: @clement not after one transaction gets stuck into txpool.

Comment: Ok so their is maybe a problem with your sealers. When you start mining can you read in the geth console something like "waiting for other signers" ?

Comment: @clement Yes that same messages displayed there..like commiting new mining then *waiting for other signers*

Comment: Ok so the problem comes from your sealers which do not communicate successfully between each others. Make sure all your sealers are mining. The number of sealers is given by the genesis file. You can see the list of sealers using `clique.getSigners()`.

Comment: If the problem persists you can update your question with your genesis file + the geth command line used to launch the nodes. It coud be helpful to identify the problem.